# PHP OOP Constructor: SELECT * vs smaller SELECT queries in getters

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I was having a discussion with a colleague today about constructors inside of PHP when working with OOP. We were discussing the most efficient way of assigning properties to an object from the database. For example, let's take a simple example and work from that (let's assume that we have a central `$db` object which is generated from a separate `Database` class):

#### Method 1:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public $id;
    public $color;
    public $transmission;

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db, $id = null)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;

        if( null !== null )
        {
            $this->id = $id;

            $obj = $this->_db->fetchObject( 'SELECT * 
                                               FROM tbl_vehicles 
                                              WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', array(':id') );

            $this->color        = $obj->color;
            $this->transmission = $obj->transmission;
        }
    }

    function get_color()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
```

#### Method 2:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public $id;

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db, $id = null)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
        $this->id  = $id;
    }

    public function get_color()
    {
        return $this->_db->fetch( 'SELECT color FROM tbl_vehicles WHERE id = :id', array(':id' => $this->id) )->color;
    }

}
```

We always hear that `SELECT *` is bad practice in MySQL, and so the question is thus: is Method 2 preferred over Method 1, since it ultimately results in more, smaller queries? Especially when dealing with arrays lots of objects, for example:

```
foreach( $vehicle->fetchAll(10) as $car )
{
    echo $car->get_color();
}
```

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: IMO, method 1 is the better approach because the persistent model (the DB) could theoretically change while you work with your class in memory. If you try to grab an attribute associated with your object after instantiation, it _could_ have been altered or deleted altogether. Unless you have a reason to use #2, my vote is for #1.

Comment: I prefer Method 2 with LIMIT 1. 

But the question is always: Which properties do you need ?

Usually in my code I have both methods: 
readVehicle($id) and readPropertyFromVehicle($property_name,$id)

Comment: Why not do a combination of both.  Put a `lazy` flag on the class that tells it not to query for everything ahead of time and in each getter just check `if($this->lazy){ /*load from db*/ }`. Then if you need all the columns, set lazy to true and it will load everything up front.

Comment: In general, you should try to reduce the number of queries. Doing a seprate query for each column is likely to be much worse than doing a single query that returns extra columns.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! That answers the question I was essentially asking.

Comment: I wouldn't couple object with db at all. Having query in the constructor you cannot effectively fetch a list of objects.

Comment: @AlexBlex How do you mean?

Comment: With 1st approach, if you need a list of 10 Vehicles, you will need to make 10 queries for each one. The most effective method is to make a single query to fetch 10 rows, then hydrate results into 10 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, actually returning the columns in a query is one of least expensive parts of it. The expensive part is generally looking up the relevant rows of the table (hopefully, this would be from the cache, but it may very well be from the disk). So once you found the row, you might as well query all the columns you're going to need in the foreseeable future (as method #1 suggests).
Moreover, most developers implicitly expect that once you've initialized an object, calling its getters would be cheap, and don't take care to avoid multiple calls. In method #2, where each getter executes a databasee query, they are anything by cheap.

Additionally, note that method #1 doesn't have to use the `*` operator. You could just explicitly state all the columns you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `SELECT *` is it loads in everything, and in some cases that's extremely painful. It's often the case that you'll have a schema with large chunks of data where a typical example is a user record that may have an extended bio, a pile of links in JSON format, and other metadata that's expensive to load. When all you need is a list of users 95% of that data will be thrown out without ever being used.

That being said, sometimes it doesn't matter, that for individual records or small, paginated lists the difference is almost immeasurable. Today a server typically has multiple GB of memory available and at least two to four cores so database queries are typically sub-millisecond. A lot of the "avoid" advice comes from twenty years ago where the difference between `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1` and an equivalent with a handful of columns would be measurably different, especially when you're shunting that data over a 10Mbit LAN.

The other problem comes when your code expects a certain number of columns in a particular order. Any schema changes to add, alter, or rearrange them will break your code if you're not paying attention to the column names that are returned. Most ORMs do a `SHOW FIELDS` or something equivalent to get a taste for the schema, then fetch those columns specifically.

That all being said, this isn't a license to use `SELECT *` freely. Use it when the difference doesn't matter, like on individual records where the cost is marginal. Use a more selective method when dealing with larger amounts of data, such as huge exports, complicated lists, and so on.

I'd also *strongly* advise you to use an existing ORM rather than write your own. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) are all well implemented, documented, and most importantly, exhaustively tested by a community that will support them.

Comment: There's nothing in his code that depends on the order of the columns. He's accessing the columns by name, not position.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just trying to explain the stigma of `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

> is Method 2 preferred over Method 1, since it ultimately results in
>   more, smaller queries?

It depends. Does your data change so fast you need to get the latest from the database every time you use a value? If so then Method 2 might be preferred.

The problem I see with your examples is that there are other differences between the exposed methods besides the use of `*`. For instance, the first method performs 1 unique call for every piece of data whilst the second one may be fetching the same data multiple times.

If the question is purely around the `*` then I believe the Method 1 should be compared to something like this, which is what I'd pick.

```
class Vehicle
{
    public $id;
    public $color;
    public $transmission;

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db, $id = null)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;

        if( $id !== null )
        {
            $this->id = $id;

            $obj = $this->_db->fetchObject( 'SELECT color, transmission 
                                               FROM tbl_vehicles 
                                              WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', array(':id') );

            $this->color        = $obj->color;
            $this->transmission = $obj->transmission;
        }
    }

    function get_color()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if( null !== null )`?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` is considered a bad practice because it fetches data from all the columns, when it's often the case you don't actually need all of them.

The best practice is to instead specify exactly which columns you want to get a tidy response.

This should also make error checking easier, because if the database version is wrong in some way and one of the columns you need doesn't exist, you will get the error right away at the moment you query, and not later.

Another thing to observe is that the examples you gave are considerably different in many ways.

Method 1 should be faster, as it will cache the information. It is, however, valid to note that if the database changes while the object exists, it will be using outdated data. Shouldn't be a problem in most cases though.

On the other hand, Method 2 will query the database every single time you call that method, which can be very performance expensive. This should be avoided except in extreme cases where you actually expect the information to change, and even so there are better ways of doing that.

All things considered, you should use Method 1, but instead of selecting everything with `SELECT *`, specify exactly what you need with `SELECT color, transmission` to achieve the same result while conforming with best practices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but regarding your last comment, bear in mind this is a pared-down example and ultimately, we likely will want `*` in the constructor.